# Is there a detailed user's documentation for KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, documentation, plasma-5

I just installed Kubuntu 15.04 and I can't find a single place with systematic description of all available desktop configuration settings. For example, I was setting *Screen Locking Timeouts* and I found by experiment that setting *Lock screen after* to 0 is the way to disable it. Another example is *Edit application-specific settings*: what is the difference between *Apply initially* and *Remember* options? Is there a single piece of documentation explaining these issues?

Answer (score 3):

The place for all KDE related User documentation is found at [KDE Userbase](https://userbase.kde.org/Welcome_to_KDE_UserBase). If you feel there are changes that should be made based on your experiences, there are a few things you can do, listed in descending order of relevance:

(1) Edit the Wiki yourself, adding the specific information you've found. Information can be found [here](https://userbase.kde.org/Tasks_and_Tools). Also see [here](https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/documentation).

(2) Contact the documentation group via IRC: [irc://irc.kde.org/kde-docs](http://irc://irc.kde.org/kde-docs)

(3) Post a message on the [Contributor's Corner](https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=304&sid=99a84d27ae29213ddcc0b1c55face036) section of the KDE Forums asking for the changes to be made or how you can most easily make them.

Help with documentation is ALWAYS needed and appreciated.

Comment: Seems like https://www.kde.org/documentation/ and https://docs.kde.org/ might be more precise actually. I'm not sure the docs will necessarily explain the difference *Apply initially* and *Remember*, however, altho they should (even better if there's a tooltip)

Comment: Also, docs bugs are filed at https://bugs.kde.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=docs