# Where is the documentation for the KDE Desktop (Plasma?)

Tags: kde

I know people rarely bother to document their stuff these days, but I'm still hopeful.

Comment: Something like this: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/plasma-desktop/index.html ? Or a pdf: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/plasma-desktop/plasma-desktop.pdf

Comment: And assuming you want help and not the documentation itself, here are some other resources: https://www.kubuntuforums.net, https://forum.kde.org, https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-users/

Comment: And a nicer way to ask the same question: [Is there a detailed user's documentation for KDE Plasma 5?](https://askubuntu.com/q/677022/248158)

Comment: Let me see. I've never opened a chat room myself. I'll try.

Comment: @blueray see if you can post in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86138/kde-plasma-matters